# How can I add a margin-left for an image only if it is shown on a separate line (small screens) using Bootstrap 4.0?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following code to show 2 images beside each others:-

```
<img style="padding-left:25%;margin-top:15px;margin-right:20%" src="~/img/1.png" /><img  style="margin-top:15px" src="~/img/2.png" />
```

as follow:-

[image]

but on smaller sized screens, the 2 image will be shown under each other (which is fine), but they will not be aligned vertically as follow:-

[image]

so how i can fix this? in other words how can I add a margin-left for the second image only if it is shown on a separate line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use media queries:

```
img {
    margin-top:15px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    img {
        padding-left:25%;
        margin-right:20%;
    }
}
```

That 768px is arbitrary, you can change it to the value you need. You can use `min-resolution` instead of `min-width` instead.

Comment: but how i can use bootstrap syntax in this? also how i can apply the media query to only the second image, and not to all images?

Comment: @testtest Bootstrap is a CSS/JS library, you should not worry about it having a separate syntax for media queries. As about your second question: you may add a class to your "second" image and use the img.yourcustomclass in your "second" image. If you have further questions, then I advise you to provide more of your structure.

Comment: thanks for the reply, now the media query worked on my windows pc on firefox,chrome and edge... but on safari iphone it did not have any effect

Comment: @testtest Safari Iphone has a width of 980 pixels (see: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html), it's probably wider than the value typed in the media query. You can try with min-width: 1000px;. Anyway, you already know how this needs to be solved, even if some details need further tweaking. If this answer has led you to the solution, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: i think you mean max-1000 to cover 980 pixels is this correct?

Comment: @testtest yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using display property with media query.

```
<div class="display">
 <img style="margin-right: 20px;" src="~/img/1.png" />
 <img src="~/img/2.png" />
</div>
```

```
.display {
  display: flex;
}
@media(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
 .display {
   display: block;
 }
}
```

Comment: but hat will happen if the screen is smaller than 320 px?

Comment: you can try the below media query when the browser window is 767px wide or less:
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
 .display {
   display: block;
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript. Listen every time window is resizing and calculate is the sum of width of all images are higher than the window width, and add margin/padding according to situation

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){ //listen to window resize
  let img1w = document.getElementById('image1').offsetWidth;
  let img2w = document.getElementById('image2').offsetWidth;
  if (img1w + img2w > window.innerWidth) {
    document.getElementById('img1w').style.marginLeft = '200px' //just a placeholder. do what you want here
  }
});
```

You can also use bootstrap media queries but there's only limited number of break points. So you have to create your own media query

Comment: Have you tried css flexbox? It is way more easier than any of these answers.